Replace prefix string from lines in a file, and put into a bash array
In the file groupAfiles.txt are the lines:
file14
file2
file4
file9

I need a way to convert them to remove file and add /dev/loop and put them all in one line with a space between them.
/dev/loop14 /dev/loop2 /dev/loop4 /dev/loop9

Then I need to put this in an array.
(but the numbers change)
How do I do this?

If you're putting the pathnames into an array, then it is irrelevant that be created with a space in-between them. Or do you also need to display them in the terminal?

is joining those /dev/loop filenames into a space-separated string the final goal, or are you doing something else with them, like passing them as arguments to some command?

Read the original names into an array:
readarray -t names <groupAfiles.txt

Replace the initial file prefix with /dev/loop:
names=( "${names[@]/#file//dev/loop}" )

The substitution used here will replace the string file at the start of each element of the names array, if that prefix string is present, with the string /dev/loop.
To display the resulting array with spaces between the elements (assuming the shell variables IFS has its default value):
printf '%s\n' "${names[*]}"

Testing:
$ cat groupAfiles.txt
file14
file2
file4
file9
$ readarray -t names <groupAfiles.txt
$ names=( "${names[@]/#file//dev/loop}" )
$ printf '%s\n' "${names[*]}"
/dev/loop14 /dev/loop2 /dev/loop4 /dev/loop9


To be clear, "${names[*]}" expands the array to one arg, with a space between elements.  The printf '%s\n' part is just a better/safer echo, in case you want to send that string to stdout instead of passing it as an arg to something else or assigning it directly to a shell variable like foo="${names[*]}" or to an element of an array of strings; future readers wanting that don't need a $(printf ...) capture for that.

To do this with awk you can use command like:
awk '{gsub("file",""); printf "/dev/loop%s ", $0}' input_file

or
awk '{gsub("file","/dev/loop"); printf "%s ", $0}' input_file

It replace file with nothing and then print /dev/loop concatenated with the number/string
To add in array you can use:
array=( $(awk '{gsub("file",""); printf "/dev/loop%s ", $0}' input_file) )


Just read it into the array and then print it space-separated as you like:
$ readarray -t files < <(sed 's:file:/dev/loop:' groupAfiles.txt)

$ declare -p files
declare -a files=([0]="/dev/loop14" [1]="/dev/loop2" [2]="/dev/loop4" [3]="/dev/loop9")

$ printf '%s\n' "${files[*]}"
/dev/loop14 /dev/loop2 /dev/loop4 /dev/loop9

